# Translating "quarente ostium" to English

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

The [official blazon](https://www.heraldry-wiki.com/heraldrywiki/index.php/University_of_Nottingham) of the University of Nottingham describes

> ... inscribed with the words 'Quarente Ostium', ...

for which I can not find a proper translation. I'm pretty sure **ostium** here refers to some type of door or opening of some sort. I'm not too sure how to translate **quarente**. I believe it could originate from quærēns (from [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Querent)) meaning something to seek, gain or ask.

Is it reasonable to translate this as seek every opening or is there a more accurate translation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The description on the website you linked is mistaken. (I believe the illustration on that site is correct, but it is too small to tell for certain. The illustration [used by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_Nottingham) is big enough but is also incorrect.) The coat of arms of the University of Nottingham really says:

> QUÆRENTI OSTIUM

… which means: **an entrance for the seeker** [of knowledge, perhaps].

An interesting discussion of the coat of arms and the role it once played and now plays, including the official heraldic description, is found [here](https://books.google.de/books?id=wb1trHzHX90C&pg=PA153#v=onepage&q&f=false) (the author opines that “this is, in one perspective, medieval gibberish”).